# Returning a list of mutually inclusive conditions with case_when

Tags: r, list, dplyr, case, tidyverse

I want to create a list-column on dataframe that can match multiple conditions using multiple columns. I tried to use `case_when` but it wouldn't work on its own because it would stop when the first condition is satisfied.

A silly but simplified example: `case2` should always have satisfy `case1`. Ideally I want a column that returns something like `c("case1", "case2")` (preferred) or `list("case1", "case2")`. However I have multiple conditions so I want to return each condition that was satisfied without explicitly setting each mutually inclusive case in the right side of the case expression.

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(x = case_when(mpg >= 15 & cyl == 6 ~ "case1",
                       mpg >= 10 ~ "case2",
                       cyl >= 7 ~ "case3",
                       mpg >= 10 ~ "case4",
                       mpg >= 10 & cyl >= 5 ~ "case5"))
```

Can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 3):

Wrap with `list` for each condition to return a `list`

```
library(dplyr)
out <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(x = case_when(mpg >= 15 & cyl == 6 ~ list("case1"),
                       mpg >= 10 ~ list(c("case1", "case2")),
                       cyl >= 7 ~ list("case3")))
```

-output

```
> head(out)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb            x
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4        case1
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4        case1
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 case1, case2
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1        case1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 case1, case2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1        case1
```

Comment: Oh this is an interesting idea, thanks! Is it possible to do this in another way though? In my use case, I have more conditions where it is more challenging to keep track of cases meeting more than 1 condition (eg. I have 10+ separate conditions to be checked).

Comment: @ThomasPrice You can add  7 more conditions in `case_when`.   Can you update your post with what you meant?  I may not have understand it properly

Comment: Sure! I can add 7 more conditions but the gist of it is that I won't want to specify each group of mutual inclusive condition manually. I'd want the list to just go through each case_when() condition and return me all the conditions that apply. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R way create a vector of conditions and their corresponding replacements.

```
conditions <- c('mpg >= 15 & cyl == 6', 'mpg >= 10', 'cyl >= 7', 
                'mpg >= 10', 'mpg >= 10 & cyl >= 5')

replacements <- paste0('case', 1:5)

apply(
  do.call(rbind, 
          Map(function(x, y) with(mtcars, ifelse(eval(parse(text = x)), y, '')), 
              conditions, replacements)), 
  2, function(x) toString(x[x!='']))

# [1] "case1, case2, case4, case5" "case1, case2, case4, case5"
# [3] "case2, case4"               "case1, case2, case4, case5"
# [5] "case2, case3, case4, case5" "case1, case2, case4, case5"
# [7] "case2, case3, case4, case5" "case2, case4"              
# [9] "case2, case4"               "case1, case2, case4, case5"
#[11] "case1, case2, case4, case5" "case2, case3, case4, case5"
#[13] "case2, case3, case4, case5" "case2, case3, case4, case5"
#[15] "case2, case3, case4, case5" "case2, case3, case4, case5"
#[17] "case2, case3, case4, case5" "case2, case4"              
#[19] "case2, case4"               "case2, case4"              
#[21] "case2, case4"               "case2, case3, case4, case5"
#[23] "case2, case3, case4, case5" "case2, case3, case4, case5"
#[25] "case2, case3, case4, case5" "case2, case4"              
#[27] "case2, case4"               "case2, case4"              
#[29] "case2, case3, case4, case5" "case1, case2, case4, case5"
#[31] "case2, case3, case4, case5" "case2, case4"
```

`Map` is used to check if a condition is `TRUE` and return the replacement or else an empty string. Combine the output for each row together, remove the empty values and return one comma-separated string.